# Do you have to be near a gym to collect defender bonus?

Tags: pokemon-go

I want to leave a couple of Pokémon in gyms, but the nearest gyms to me are still some distance away and I can't go there every day. If I leave Pokémon there as gym defenders, can I collect the bonus at home or do I need to be within range of the gym?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to be near it, but most likely your Pokemon will get KO pretty quickly since there's no way to really defend yourself at gyms.  Just see how long it takes for you to lose those defenders and gauge when to collect.

Answer (score 8):

You do not need to be at the gym, you can collect your bonus from any location in the shop screen by tapping the shield icon on the top right.

Comment: You should also take note that the bonus is multiplicative relative to the number of gyms that you are currently defending. So it would make little sense to have to be near all gyms you own to get the full rewards.

Comment: @Karlyr Feel free to suggest an edit if you think my answer can be improved.